# Modify Script to Copy Alt Attribute to Thumbnails

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery, image-gallery, photo-gallery

I'm tweaking a gallery plugin for a site that I'm working on, so that it will support titles. This is this script I'm working with:

DEMO: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager2.html
CODE: http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js

I have everything working, except I need the alt attribute from the original image to be copied to the thumbnails on load, but I can't figure out where things are getting restructured in this script.

This is the modification that I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#slideshow-wrap #nav li a img").click(function() {
        var caption = $(this).attr("alt");
        $("#slideshow-wrap #caption").html(caption);
    });
});
```

(The above code works, I just need to copy the ALT attribute from the original `<img>` to the jQuery-generated `<img>` thumbnail.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you need, the changes you have to make to the example given on the page are minimal:

```
pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
    return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + slide.src + '" width="50" height="50" />' + slide.alt + '</a></li>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly after some minor tweaks :) (`alt="' + slide.alt + '"`)